# How to create array of a particular field of json string through collect() method of objx

Tags: javascript, jquery

my json string is as follows:

```
var data = [{"first":"3","second":"1"},{"first":"5","second":"5"},{"first":"7","second":"1"}];
```

Now i am calling -

```
objx(data).collect("first")
```

and expecting to get an array like [3,5,7].
But i am getting javascript error : object doesn't support this property or method.
i have tried with

```
objx(data).collect("first").obj() but with no avail.
```

i have included objx-2.3.6.js file from http://code.google.com/p/objx/ and i want to create the array with objx api to reduce no of lines of code.
i am using IE8

please suggest a way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"my json string"* - That's neither JSON nor a string. Anyway...

Since you've tagged your question with jQuery (even though you don't mention it in your question anywhere) here is a jQuery solution to the same problem:

```
var fields = $.map(data, function(val) { return val.field; });
// fields is [3,5,7]
```

As far as why you're getting the particular error you do, that would be because the `.collect()` method is not part of the core objx library, at least, it is not in `objx-2.3.6.js`. Presumably you need to include the Collections plugin js too (but I couldn't find it).

Comment: thanks a lot. it's working. But can u please tell me why it is not a valid json string.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you're using the wrong terminology. In the code shown you don't have any JSON, because JSON is a _string_ representation of an object (usually) used for data interchange. What you have is an array (a type of object) that you're creating with an array literal that contains object literals. JavaScript objects are not the same thing as JSON, they just use similar syntax.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i have one doubt. In my example can you please point out which are array and object literals in my example. can you please show what would have been the the JSON string representation of my example.

Comment: Array literals have square brackets with comma separated values: `[1,2,3]`. Object literals have curly braces with comma separated key/value pairs: `{"first":"3","second":"1"}`. String literals have single or double quotes: `"I'm a string"` and `'Also a string'`. Regex literals have forward slashes: `/regexpatternhere/`. So your `data` is an array (square brackets) where each element is an object (curly braces). The JSON string representation of that object would look exactly the same except it would have to be a _string_, so with quotation marks: `data = '[{"first":"3","second":"1"}, etc]'`

Answer (score 2):

`collect` has to be added to `objx` as plugin

see doc : https://code.google.com/p/objx/wiki/Plugins

Add the plugin file for collect function

https://objx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/src/collections/collect.js

```
var data = [{"first":"3","second":"1"},{"first":"5","second":"5"},{"first":"7","second":"1"}];


objx(data).collect("first", function(array){
    alert(array);
});
```

Comment: +1. I couldn't find that plugin to download - for some reason the download page wouldn't display properly in IE7 (which is all I have on this workstation) even though other pages about objx displayed fine. Hence my jQuery-based answer.

Comment: spot on! i have been searching for this.now my search is over.thanks.